# Mac OS X 10.14.6 Add option to Right Click Menu in Finder

Tags: finder, mojave, automator, contextual-menu

I'd like to add a new option to the right click menu in finder that would have the same effect as the command line
`% touch $(pwd)`
i.e. this will bring the folder to the top of the list when I have finder windows sorted on Date Modified.

Comment: What has your research shown so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have seen answers elsewhere that suggest use of Automator.app. However, they refer to creating a new plugin or service, but neither option seems available in the version I have. A new Quick Action would seem to be what I need and I can create a one-line Shell Script that does what I want, however I can't see how to pass the path of the object that I'm right clicking on into the script as an argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **Automator**, create a new *Service/Quick Action* adding a **Run Shell Script** *action*, with settings for both as shown in the image below.

Save it as, e.g.,: **Touch**

It will then be available on the **Quick Actions** *menu* as well as the **Services** menu.

Note that you could also create this as an **Automator** *application* and add it to the **Toolbar** in **Finder** using *drag & drop*, with **⌘** down as necessary. However, while not absolutely necessary, I'd first give it a nice icon via its **Info** *sheet* before adding it to the **Toolbar**.

*Example* **shell script** *code*:

```bash
for f in "$@"
do
    touch "$f"
done
```

---

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks for your answer. Exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Mike Yearworth, I've done this for as long as I've been using a **Mac**. It definitely comes in handy.

Comment: Suggestion:  add this to the `touch` : `-t 203801010001` to make it show up at the top for the next 17 years or so. Or `-t 226201010001` to make it show up at the top for the foreseeable future/thru 2261.  (I think I had 2038 because HFS+ could't handle dates past 2038.)

Comment: @Matthew Elvey-RNSTT IVERMECTIN, RE: "Suggestion: add this to the `touch` : `-t 203801010001` to make it show up at the top for the next 17 years or so." --  Why!? There was no mentioned in the OP for `touch` to use the `-t` _option_ and the answer was marked as the accepted answer, which means it answered his question satisfactorily.

Comment: @ user: OP @MikeYearworth wants something that "will bring the folder to the top of the list when I have finder windows sorted on Date Modified" this would do so AND cause it to STAY there even as new files were created.

Comment: I agree that the addition of the future date with `-t` adds substantially to the original answer. Frequently users, myself included, either makes limiting guesses about the direction of a solution or do not ask complete questions. If someone is able to read between the lines, they should not be faulted for answering something other than the users literal question.